# Ecto relations, not inserting foreign key ids

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Sup,
I'm learning Ecto and I'm trying to insert record with association to another table. It is kinda working, because record is being inserted but foreign key field is empty.

Code:

```
parent = Repo.get(Hangman.MasterCat, parent_id)
changeset = build(parent, :categories)
  |> Category.changeset( params)
IO.inspect(changeset)

if changeset.valid? do
  Repo.insert(changeset)
  json conn, ResponseUtils.jsonResponse(true)
else
  json conn, ResponseUtils.jsonResponse(false,["parents doesn't exist"])
end
```

Inspection of changeset

```
%Ecto.Changeset{action: nil, changes: %{name: "Kategory 1"}, constraints: [],
 errors: [], filters: %{},
 model: %{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:built>, __struct__: Hangman.Category,

   id: nil, inserted_at: nil, master_cat_id: 1,
   mastercat: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :mastercat is not loaded>,

   mastercat_id: nil, name: nil, updated_at: nil,
   words: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :words is not loaded>},
 optional: [], opts: [], params: %{"name" => "Kategory 1"}, repo: nil,
 required: [:name],
 types: %{id: :id, inserted_at: Ecto.DateTime, mastercat_id: :id, name: :string,

   updated_at: Ecto.DateTime,
   words: {:assoc,
    %Ecto.Association.Has{cardinality: :many, defaults: [], field: :words,
     on_cast: :changeset, on_delete: :nothing, on_replace: :raise,
     owner: Hangman.Category, owner_key: :id, queryable: Hangman.Word,
     related: Hangman.Word, related_key: :category_id}}}, valid?: true,
 validations: []}
```

What I can see is for some weird reason it assigns the parent id to field master_cat_id instead of mastercat_id.

Any help is much appreciated.
https://github.com/Hajto/hangmanelixir

Comment: Also please don't use "changeset.valid?", use `case Repo.insert(...) do` and pattern match on the results.

Comment: @JoséValim Thank you very much for the tip

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The foreign key is inferred from the module name by the `association_key/2` function in the (deliberately undocumented) `Ecto.Association` module:

```
iex(1)> Ecto.Association.association_key(User, :id)
:user_id
iex(3)> Ecto.Association.association_key(FooBar, :id)           
:foo_bar_id
iex(5)> Ecto.Association.association_key(MasterCat, :id)
:master_cat_id
```

Change the [belongs_to/3](http://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#belongs_to/3) schema to use an explicit foreign key field name:

```
   schema "categories" do
    field :name, :string

    has_many :words, Hangman.Word
    belongs_to :mastercat, Hangman.MasterCat, foreign_key: :master_cat_id

    timestamps
  end
```

Comment: After a bit of tinkering it worked! Thank you very much.